# Fabricjs zoom and pan to match vis-network fit

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, zooming, fabricjs, vis.js

I am using [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) to allow users to draw objects in the background of a network displayed using [vis-network](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/).  One of the features of vis-network is the `fit()` function, which zooms and pans the network so that it will neatly and entirely fit within the window.  However, I need to zoom and pan the background (i.e. the fabricjs `canvas`) to match. I am finding it difficult to work out how to do this.

My code so far looks like this:

```
function myfit() {
    let prevPos = network.getViewPosition()
    let oldScale = network.getScale()
    network.fit({
        position: {x: 0, y: 0},
    })
    let newPos = network.getViewPosition()
    let newScale = network.getScale()
    panCanvas((prevPos.x - newPos.x) * oldScale, (prevPos.y - newPos.y) * oldScale)
    zoomCanvas(newScale)
}
function zoomCanvas(zoom) {
    canvas.zoomToPoint({x: canvas.getWidth() / 2, y: canvas.getHeight() / 2}, zoom)
}

function panCanvas(x, y) {
    let zoom = network.getScale()
    canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(x * zoom, y * zoom))
}
```

Both `panCanvas` and `zoomCanvas` work as they should, i.e. if the network is zoomed in or out and `zoomCanvas` called with the new zoom level (obtained from `network.getScale()`), the background objects are zoomed in or out to match (e..g if a fabric `rect` is overlaid on a network node, it stays overlaid after the zoom).  `panCanvas` also works.  However, if `myfit()` is used to fit the network in the window, and the final zoom level (`newScale`) is not 1 (which is the case if the whole network is too large to fit in the window, so `vis-network` reduces the zoom until it does), the fabric objects are displaced.  It seems that some other formula for the amount of pan is needed.

The vis-network `fit()` function argument  `position: {x: 0, y: 0}` centres the network in the middle. `network.getViewPosition()` returns the current central focus point of the view.

An example is shown below.  In the first image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rLY9.png), red and black fabric rectangle objects have been placed over two of the network nodes.  Another node (node 13)is outside the view and not visible.  Then `myfit()` is called and the result is the second image [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRCjH.png).  The network has been shrunk and centred, and node 13 is not visible, but the fabric rectangles are no longer over their nodes, as they should be.

[image: Network before fitting]

[image: Network after fitting]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I eventually worked it out.  The rule is, always pan at zoom 1.  That may mean that you have to record the current zoom, zoom to 1, pan, and then revert to the previous zoom level.  The working version of `myfit` is:

```js
function myfit() {
    let prevPos = network.getViewPosition()
    network.fit({
        position: {x: 0, y: 0}, // fit to centre of canvas
    })
    let newPos = network.getViewPosition()
    let newScale = network.getScale()
    zoomCanvas(1.0)
    panCanvas((prevPos.x - newPos.x), (prevPos.y - newPos.y), 1.0)
    zoomCanvas(newScale)
}
function zoomCanvas(zoom) {
    canvas.zoomToPoint({x: canvas.getWidth() / 2, y: canvas.getHeight() / 2}, zoom)
}

function panCanvas(x, y) {
    let zoom = network.getScale()
    canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(x * zoom, y * zoom))
}
```